# Angular nativeElement contains() not working as expected for document:click

Tags: angular

I've got code to detect if somewhere outside a component is being clicked, problem is that one of the elements `dropdown-items` inside my component is being detected as a click outside the component. Could be to do with the ngIf..

```
if (!this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target))
```

**some of the template:**

```
  <div class="dropdown-items" *ngIf="showList">
    <div *ngFor="let item of dropdownItems" (click)="onClickItem(item)" class="dropdown-item">
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

So when the dropdown list is expanded, then items clicked from the list the `toggleShowList` is called when it shouldn't be.

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  documentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (!this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.toggleShowList();
      console.log('clicked window outside button');
    }
  }
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. Could you edit https://angular-dropdown-j712f6.stackblitz.io and create minimal reproducible example of your issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular. How to define a click outside, excluding sub-components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559275/angular-how-to-define-a-click-outside-excluding-sub-components)